# Поведение метода stop()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть блок и скрытый абзац. При щелчке по блоку абзац анимационно появляется. У анимации отображения есть метод stop со значениями 0,0(false, false). Но так же есть Условные операторы: if который не выполняется первый раз. В его теле тоже есть stop но, со значениями 1,1(true, true). Вопрос: почему даже если if не выполняется stop ведёт себя будто у него значение 1,1 ?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 

$('.q1').click(function(){ 
if($(this).next().is(':visible')) // Это не выполняется т.к. Абзац ещё не виден
$(this).next().stop(true,true).slideUp(); // Это не выполняется т.к. Абзац ещё не виден

$(this).next().stop(0,0).slideToggle();//Так почему у stop ведёт себя будто у него значение true,true ?
}); 

});
```

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.q1{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background: red;
}
p{
    width:150px;
  height:300px;
  background: black;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="q1"></div>
<p></p>
```

Comment: Вопрос: почему даже если if не выполняется stop ведёт себя будто у него значение 1,1 ?
Так почему у stop ведёт себя будто у него значение false false ?
Поему у вас два разных вопроса? на который тут нужно отвечать?

Comment: @Олександр Опечатка. Исправил.

Comment: Нет объяснений?

Comment: Не могу понять какое поведение вы ожидаете. `stop` одинаково **никак** себя ведет, когда никакой анимации не происходит

Comment: @Crantisz Если 2 раза быстро нажать на блок то произойдёт анимация  присуща настройкам stop(true,true).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давайте разберемся, что происходит когда вы нажимаете 2 раза подряд по кнопке.

**1 нажатие**

`.is(':visible'))` Тут у нас `false` пропускаем <s>`.stop(true,true).slideUp();`</s>

`.stop(0,0).slideToggle();`  Абзац начинает появляться. Тут все понятно.

**2 нажатие**

`.is(':visible'))` Тут у нас `true`. Хоть абзац еще не весь появился, *но он уже виден*!

`.stop(true,true).slideUp();` Прыгаем в конец анимации. И начинаем скрывать блок.

`.stop(0,0).slideToggle();` Стопорим анимацию в самом начале и начинаем скрывать блок.

Comment: А если добавить $(this).next().stop(0,0); перед оператором if то переопределяется https://jsfiddle.net/c4moLg2a/ и при двойном щелчке stop работает со значениями (0, 0)

Comment: @PeGaS тогда не понятно зачем все это надо, когда можно одной строкой обойтись https://jsfiddle.net/c4moLg2a/1/

Comment: Последний нюанс. Просто почему stop работает как 0,0 если при двойном щелчке когда происходит значение в if и у stop там указан 1,1 ? https://jsfiddle.net/cpdg5kza/

Comment: Или stop в теле if не срабатывает потому что, очереди уже нет из-за ранее сработавшим span с 0,0